# AppBlock blocks AppBlock

Tags: android, data-access-app-block

When I try to open Appblock, it says Appblock is blocked by Appblock. Somehow I added appblock itself to be blocked mistakenly. What should I do? It doesnt let me to enter pincode to open appblock. Can you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have a rooted device to change the app's data, afaik the only thing you can do is navigate to app's global settings & clear the app data.